# Cannot invoke method registerTransform() on null object

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

A weird problem happened when i build my project which worked well. Error infos as following

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method registerTransform() on null object
    at com.mob.products.MobApmConfig.registerTransform(MobApmConfig.groovy:67)
    at com.mob.products.MobApmConfig$registerTransform.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.mob.products.MobApmConfig$registerTransform.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.mob.MobSDKConfig.processMobApm(MobSDKConfig.groovy:1102)
    at com.mob.MobSDKConfig.processShareSDK(MobSDKConfig.groovy:666)
    at com.mob.MobSDKConfig.ShareSDK(MobSDKConfig.groovy:582)
    at com.mob.MobSDKConfig_Decorated.ShareSDK(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:483)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.ConfigureDelegate.invokeMethod(ConfigureDelegate.java:56)
    at MobSDK_69n0s3w6cei5e2fvsr1nnkg2i$_run_closure1.doCall(C:\Users\Administrator\StudioProjects\wedeep\MobSDK.gradle:8)
    at org.gradle.util.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:154)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:105)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$WrappedConfigureAction.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.ExtensionsStorage$ExtensionHolder.configure(ExtensionsStorage.java:173)
    at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.ExtensionsStorage.configureExtension(ExtensionsStorage.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.DefaultConvention.configureExtension(DefaultConvention.java:364)
    at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.DefaultConvention.access$500(DefaultConvention.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.DefaultConvention$ExtensionsDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(DefaultConvention.java:301)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.java:34)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript$ScriptDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BasicScript.java:134)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:162)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.invokeMethod(BasicScript.java:83)
    at MobSDK_69n0s3w6cei5e2fvsr1nnkg2i.run(C:\Users\Administrator\StudioProjects\wedeep\MobSDK.gradle:3)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
```

My gradle file MobSDK.gradle.
apply plugin: 'com.mob.sdk'

```
MobSDK {

    appKey "***********"
    appSecret "***********"

    ShareSDK {

        version '3.7.3'

        loopShare false

        gui true

        //平台配置信息
        devInfo {
            Wechat {
                id 1
                sortId 1
                appId "***********"
                appSecret "***********"
                bypassApproval false
                enable true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my build.gradle which depend MobSDK.gradle.(only key part is posted)

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply from: "../MobSDK.gradle"
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
```

Any ideas for me? Thanks for first!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheDynamicVersionsFor 1,'seconds'
}
```

to `build.gradle`(project)

Comment: Not work for me, I still get that problem after i updated my build.gradle config

Comment: Is project `build.gradle`, Not module `build.gradle`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried it, but still not work.

Comment: Oh my god,  It works when i tried it at the second time.  It's truly weird.